# Wordpress get_permalink bug - does not return clean URLs in admin area?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.5.2

I have set all my site urls to the custom structure in Permalink Settings:

```
/portfolio/%postname%/
```

But when I try to get a post clean URL **in my admin area** at `http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=415&action=edit`:

```
// Get post/page ID.
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

get_permalink($post->ID);
```

Result:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?p=415
```

But it **should be**:

```
http://mywebsite.com/portfolio/sample-1/
```

Why? What have I missed?

Comment: Where you try to get this permalink? I think that permalinks are available on the frontend is already checked. So on which admin-page you try to access them, from where you receive the page/post-id and at last: Do this page already exists when you try to access them? (sorry for the dump questions, but that's important)

Comment: `Do this page already exists when you try to access them?` yes they do.

Comment: `Where you try to get this permalink?` for instance from  `http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=415&action=edit`

Comment: Are u make sure .htaccess CHMOD 644 or something similar. If now is 444 you will can't use permalink setting.

Comment: it is already set to 777.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of it is that the page has no **slug** data. Only the slug data is stored then I can get the clean URL.